# PHP cURL string get everything before and after certain part of string

Tags: php, string, curl, str-replace, explode

Im usin cURL to crabb some data from webpage. 
But as the data is array based, but the size changes and varies.
Then i need to search for parts of string and want to get everyhting after the 
part til next comma.

```
{"id":2988001,"teatiseNr":"50000099027","mkood":74,
```

Now here is the string. 
I would only like to have everything after **{"id":**
til the first comma. 
So my output would be **2988001**

Why i need the search criteria is because some times there are more variables and that messes up the order. 
Right now im using simple

```
$pieces = explode(",", $page);
```

And then just delete the rest with

```
str_replace('{"id":','',$pieces[0]);
```

There must be more elegant way to make this work.

Comment: Is this whole string your response? It looks like json, so you should use ``json_decode($page, true)`` to give you an associative array.

Comment: Yes it is, but i dont know what to do when variables chance, then my sql query goes to hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this  is a json string, so you can simply do:

```
$data = json_decode($string);

echo $data->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is array based then alistaircol, matei, and neil are right you should use something like

```
$data = json_decode($page);
$id = $data->id
```

Let's say for some reason the response actually not JSON and the order of the item with id is variable then something like this could work too

```
$no_braces = str_ireplace('{','',$page);
$no_quotes = str_ireplace('"','',$no_braces);
$items = explode(",",$no_quotes);
function getID($items){
    foreach($items as $item){
         $parts = explode($item, ':');
         $key = $parts[0];
         if($key === 'id'){
             return $parts[1];
         }
    }
    return null;
}
```